# How to get dynamic label entries with Glade and Gtk

Tags: python, ubuntu, gtk, glade

I am making an application that takes input from a gyroscope and accelerometer and displays that information in the GUI. How can I display this dynamic information with glade? Is there a way to have a label reflect a variable in my code? I am using python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display data on a Gtk.Label defined on a glade file you must, load the glade file with Gtk.Builder:

```
builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("your_file.glade")
```

Then retrieve the label, with the given ID (the widget name you gave to the label, let suppose it was **label1**):

```
label = builder.get_object("label1")
```

From then on, you can use `label.set_text` or `label.set_markup` methods to update the label.

This info applies to Gtk3 and PyGObject.